# `make install` with CMake + SWIG + Python

Tags: c++, python, makefile, cmake, swig

I am writing a C++ library which can be used from both C++ and Python on Mac and Linux. So I have decided to use CMake and SWIG for my project.

As well described in the SWIG 2.0 documentation, combination of SWIG and CMake also works fine on my Mac.
http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Introduction_build_system

But I have a question about `make install`.

After typing `cmake .` and `make`, `_example.so` was successfully generated. But `make install` does not work, because the auto-generated Makefile does not have `install` target. I would like to know how I can add `install` target in the Makefile. I would like `_example.so` to be installed under `site-packages` directory on each system.

I would very appreciate it if anyone could tell me how to modify the CMake example written in the above link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CMake interface to `make install` is the CMake command [install()](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3ainstall). In your example, you could add an installation rule like this:

```
install(
  TARGETS ${SWIG_MODULE_example_REAL_NAME} 
  # ... add other arguments to install() as necessary
)
```

Once there are any `install()` commands in a CMakeList, CMake will generate an `install` target callable as `make install`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will add an answer to show the whole commands.

Comment: Wondered how to generate that variable name dynamically… Despite my expectation, `${SWIG_MODULE_${PROJECT_NAME}_REAL_NAME}` seems to work!

Answer (score 10):

```
find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)

include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})
set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set_source_files_properties(target.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
set_source_files_properties(target.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall")
swig_add_module(target python target.i ${SOURCES})
swig_link_libraries(target ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})

execute_process(COMMAND python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()" OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
install(TARGETS _target DESTINATION ${PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES})
install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/target.py DESTINATION ${PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES})
```

Comment: How does this work if the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is set to a local directory? The PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES will point to a system folder and not use the prefix...

Comment: I found the answer in the libftdi python CMakeLists.txt file. I don't understand it well enough to respond with any updates yet but for anyone also interested check out http://developer.intra2net.com/git/?p=libftdi;a=blob;f=python/CMakeLists.txt;h=93410544fac2a45eec51cb8dd344708b3bbdfe67;hb=HEAD

Comment: This behaviour is as expected in the Python world. The library gets installed into the environment that a naive call to python would use. This lets you install into the currently activated virtualenv or what have you.